# Regular expression for words and real numbers

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

I'm having trouble building a function that extracts words and real numbers, and replaces another symbols with empty spaces.

For example:

```
word1, word2.word3, 1.4056 -1.2456 40,50 -60$30 60.50. 70.40.
```

should become

```
word1 word2 word3 1.4056 -1.2456 40 50 -60 30 60.50 70.40
```

I tried with:

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+", " ", input_string)
```

I almost have it, except `60.50.` doesn't change (the trailing dot is still there). Could you help me please?

Comment: What should happen to "1.2.3"?

Comment: And with your regex, 70.40. should have stayed 70.40., so you're not showing the actual output.

Comment: What is a "word"? Would `QWZ` be kept?

Comment: The question says *"should bevome ..."* and goes on to want `word2` and `word3` separate, but I would expect the given Regex to keep them together as `word2.word3`. So the question seems inconsistent as it says that only `60.50.` is returned wrongly.

Comment: if you have a variety of dissimilar changes, often it's better to make the changes in a few rounds

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\.(?!\d)|[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]+", " ", input_string)
```

Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 1.4056 -1.2456 40 50 -60 30 60.50  70.40
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a *find-and-replace*, you can use the *[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.findall)* function, and concatenate the results using *[str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.findall)*.

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+
```

```py
string = 'word1, word2.word3, 1.4056 -1.2456 40,50 -60$30 60.50. 70.40.'
matches = re.findall(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+', string)
string = str.join(' ', matches)
```

Output

```
word1 word2 word3 1.4056 -1.2456 40 50 -60 30 60.50 70.40
```